# html - body margin-top:40px not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a top bar and shift whole body down by 40px.

```
$('body').attr('style','margin-top:40px;');
```

This adds style element to body and is seen when I inspect element but it does not shift the body down.

Comment: try `$('body').css('margin-top','40px;');`

Comment: $('body').attr('style','margin-top:40px !important');

Comment: tried it `$('body').css('margin-top','40px!important');` not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it have many ways to do for example:

```
$('body').attr('style','margin-top:40px !important');
```

if you want pure JavaScript code you can use this:

```
document.body.style.marginTop = "40px";
```

use jQuery css funtion

```
$(body).css('margin-top': '40px');
```

Comment: `$('body').attr('style','margin-top:40px !important');` seem to work.. thanks